# python replace() not working as expected

Tags: python

My script is supposed to write html files changing the html menu to show the current page as class="current_page_item" so that it will be highlighted when rendered. It has to do two replacements, first set the previous current page to be not current, then set the new current page to current. The two writeText.replace lines do not appear to have any effect. It doesn't give me an error or anything. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
for each in startList:
    sectionName = s[each:s.find("\n",each)].split()[1]
    if sectionName[-3:] <> "-->":
        end = s.find("end "+sectionName+'-->')
        sectionText =  s[each+len(sectionName)+12:end-1]
        writeText = templatetop+"\n"+sectionText+"\n"+templatebottom
        writeText.replace('<li class="current_page_item">','<li>')
        writeText.replace('<li><a href="'+sectionName+'.html','<li class="current_page_item"><a href="'+sectionName+'.html')
        f = open(sectionName+".html", 'w+')
        f.write(writeText)
        f.close()
```

Here is part of the string I am targeting (templatetop):

```
<li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="history.html" accesskey="2" title="">History</a></li>
<li><a href="members.html" accesskey="3" title="">Members</a></li>
```

Comment: Strings are immutable in python.

Comment: on a side note `!=` is much more readable than `<>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`replace` [returns](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) the resulting string, so you need to do this:

```
writeText = writeText.replace('<li class="current_page_item">','<li>')
writeText = writeText.replace('<li><a href="'+sectionName+'.html','<li class="current_page_item"><a href="'+sectionName+'.html')
```

Comment: Just to add a little clarity to this response, replace returns a string because a string itself is immutable. In order to change a string, you must return a new instance of a string with the corresponding updates

Comment: @John as a tip for the future, you may find it rewarding to experiment with unfamiliar functions in the Python (or ipython: http://ipython.org/index.html) interactive shell.  This will prevent you from making assumptions that can be proved as false through simple experimentation.  That, and keep the documentation close by.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You should not expect that to work, because you should read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

> **Return a copy of the string** with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.

Answer (score 1):

So first you replace `'<li class="current_page_item">'` with `'<li>'` and then you replace `'<li>'` with `'<li class="current_page_item">'`. That's a bit funny, I have to say.

In addition to the problem pointed out by misha, that replace returns the result, your two replacements in fact cancel each other out.

```
>>> writeText = """<li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
... <li><a href="history.html" accesskey="2" title="">History</a></li>
... <li><a href="members.html" accesskey="3" title="">Members</a></li>"""
>>> result = writeText.replace('<li class="current_page_item">','<li>')>>> result = result.replace('<li><a href="index.html','<li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html')
>>> result == writeText
True
```

Now this is just the first iteration of replacements, but it's a good indication that you are using the wrong solution. It also means you can simply remove the first of the replacements and it will still work.

Also, why are you doing the replacement on writeText, when you are only targeting templatetop?

Comment: umm thats not at all what hes doing look closer at second replace

Comment: Well, yes and no. Actually only the first iteration of substitutions cancel each other out. But that makes the first substitution pointless.